# Wrapping text around sideways table

Tags: tables, wrapfigure, landscape

I am trying to figure out how to "wrap" portrait-orientated text around a table that is rotated to landscape.

With a portrait-orientated table, this can be easily achieved using the -wrapfig- package and the wraptable environment, however, I cannot work out how to do this when the table needs to be ROTATED 90degrees (i.e., landscaped).

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{sidewaystable}[h]
\footnotesize
\centering
\caption[]{\label{tab:summary}\centerline{\textbf{Summary Statistics---blah 
blah}} \\ \footnotesize \lipsum[1]}
\begin{tabular}{lccccccccc}
\toprule
\multicolumn{10}{c}{Summary Statistics (stuff v stuff)} \\
\midrule
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) \\
\\
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Stuff} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Stuff} & Stuff \\
\\
stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & 
stuff \\
\\
\midrule
\\    
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

This produces a paragraph on page 1 and then the table on page 2. What I am trying to do is WRAP the text on page 1 AROUND the table on page 2 while preserving the orientation of the text.

Comment: The environment `sidewaystable` is always on a new page (as far as I know).

Comment: And [welome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: True, sidewaystable creates a page-sized float. I was doing this more as an example to illustrate what i wanted :)

Comment: Looks like this solution should work: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/627553/wrap-text-around-rotated-table-and-caption

Answer (score 2):

Utilizing the `wrapfig` package and the `rotating` package you could use something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wraptable}{l}{6cm}

\footnotesize
\centering
\caption[]{Summary Statistics---blah blah\label{tab:summary}}
\begin{sideways}
\begin{tabular}{l*9c}
\toprule
\multicolumn{10}{c}{Summary Statistics (stuff v stuff)} \\
\midrule
(1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8) & (9) & (10) \\
\\
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Stuff} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Stuff} & Stuff \\
\\
stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & stuff & 
stuff \\
\\
\midrule
\\    
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\
 X  &    123  & 123  & 123  & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123   & 123  & 123 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{sideways}
\end{wraptable}
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I was hoping to keep the caption rotated too though :(

Comment: @kgs `\caption` inside `sideways` doesn't work. You could use something like: `\multicolumn{10}{c}{\refstepcounter{table}\label{tab:summary}Table~\thetable: Summary Statistics---blah blah}\\[0.5ex]` as the first line of the table to rotate the caption, too, though this would not use the `\caption` command